# How to display exponential results?

Tags: exponential-distribution

So I have some results which are both exponential, but this is expected, however I want to graphically display these results. I think the best way to display them is via a line chart, but of course the exponential nature of the data makes the line graph pretty unintelligible.

Here is the data: 
[Exponential Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42vUb.png)

And here is the graph i've got at the moment.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS7lc.png)

My question is, what would be the best way to show these results? Would taking the log be the correct method?

Comment: Depending on what you're interested in, the graph you have may be fairly informative. It tells you that the explosion of states happens after 40 moves, and everything before that is relatively trivial in size. If you need to be able to distinguish trends before 40 moves, however, try a logarithmic vertical axis.

Comment: Thank you @DavidK I will give it a go and post results